# ThreeJS Match GLTF Model To Size Of Bounding Box

Tags: javascript, three.js, scale

I want to scale the imported GLB Model to the same size a cube in my scene. It is needed to make sure that the model stays inside the shadow casting areas and is big enough to make the shadows visible.

I 've calculated the bounding Boxes of both objects already:

```
// shadowcasting area 
var sceneExtent = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 4, 4, 4 );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( sceneExtent, material );
var sceneBounds = sceneExtent.computeBoundingBox()
```

and

```
// imported mesh
model.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if ( child.isMesh ) {
        child.geometry.computeBoundingBox()
        meshBounds = child.geometry.boundingBox
    }
} );
```

but now I do not know what to do with them to modify the `scale` of the GLTF Model

```
// meshBounds = child.geometry.boundingBox
// sceneBounds = sceneExtent.computeBoundingBox()

// how to resize model scale to match size of sceneBounds

model.scale.set(1,1,1)
```

I've already researched quite a bit but I do not seem to understand the solutions I've found so far.

How can I modify the model scale to match the `sceneBounds` with the information I have?

UPDATE: To get the bounding box use `.setFromObject()` instead:

```
sceneBounds = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( cube );
meshBounds = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( model );
```

Comment: I would calculate the length of each side (x, y, z) of both bounding boxes and then calculate the quotient of them. Then use that ratio to set the scale. If the bounding box of your glb-model isn't exactly cubic, which means you will have different ratios on the axes, you need to use the smallest or biggest ratio, by sorting them, to contain the model within the cube. If you need help with the code, let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I could use some help with the code. I'm not sure how to apply the method you descripted (as it was the case for all the other solutions I found). If you could show me in code how to do what you described, that would be really great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example like this:

```
// Calculate side lengths of scene (cube) bounding box
let lengthSceneBounds = {
  x: Math.abs(sceneBounds.max.x - sceneBounds.min.x),
  y: Math.abs(sceneBounds.max.y - sceneBounds.min.y),
  z: Math.abs(sceneBounds.max.z - sceneBounds.min.z),
};

// Calculate side lengths of glb-model bounding box
let lengthMeshBounds = {
  x: Math.abs(meshBounds.max.x - meshBounds.min.x),
  y: Math.abs(meshBounds.max.y - meshBounds.min.y),
  z: Math.abs(meshBounds.max.z - meshBounds.min.z),
};

// Calculate length ratios
let lengthRatios = [
  (lengthSceneBounds.x / lengthMeshBounds.x),
  (lengthSceneBounds.y / lengthMeshBounds.y),
  (lengthSceneBounds.z / lengthMeshBounds.z),
];

// Select smallest ratio in order to contain the model within the scene
let minRatio = Math.min(...lengthRatios);

// If you need some padding on the sides
let padding = 0;
minRatio -= padding;

// Use smallest ratio to scale the model
model.scale.set(minRatio, minRatio, minRatio);
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that as soon as possible. When everything checks out I will accept your answer. This was very helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked like a charm thanks a lot! But to get the bounding box I had to do it differently. To make this work I had to use `var sceneBounds = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( cube );`  and for the model `meshBounds = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( model );` but other than that this works!